# Get user login name and address on bad login attempt [Dovecot]

Tags: authentication, dovecot

**Background**
I am trying to develop a method to ban users who exhibit strange behavior when logging into Dovecot by obtaining their POP-ID/login name and IP address. I want to send that information to a separate program/process that is responsible for banning the users.  The caveat is this has to be possible through Dovecot (not looking at system logs or other programs, but a program or process that Dovecot spawns on a bad login attempt).

**Question**
How do you get the POP-ID/login name and IP address of a user when their authentication fails?

Comment: Did some research and it looks like I should try and configure the anvil service to run a script when authentication fails. Unfortunately, the details to configure anvil like this aren't available. For reference, these are the official documents on [Dovcot Service Configuration](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Services).

Comment: Check file /var/log/mail.log for failed logins. Consider installing `fail2ban`.

Comment: I'm in 100% agreement with you on both of those. My boss wants to use a "pre-login" script or something that is not "fail2ban". I have suggested both of your options to my superiors.

Comment: `fail2ban` is actively developed and has lots of users. I bet this provides a better security than a homegrown solution with only one company using it. More users => more eyes ==> more security.

Comment: I'll see if I can convince my boss. I agree with you though.